# How to get all locals passed from server to clients in jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Is it possible to get all  locals passed from server in a jade like this:

```
express:

res.render('index', {
  title: 'My Title',
  p1: 1,
  p1: 2,
  p1: 3,
  p1: 4
});

jade:

 html
   head
   body
     script
        var all_locals = _.getLocals(); // all_locals => { title: 'My Title', p1: 1,    p1: 2, p1: 3, p1: 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correct, you can wrap all your variables in one variable, and send it with [res.render()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render).

```
//in express
all_locals = {
  title: 'My Title',
  p1: 1,
  p2: 2,
  p3: 3,
  p4: 4
};
res.render('upload.jade',{all_locals: JSON.stringify(all_locals)});

//in jade
var all_locals = !{all_locals};
alert(all_locals.title);
```

Comment: Yes I know. But I don't want to wrap all variables in one variable.